# Simple Fluid layout with images - different fluid response in FF and Android

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

I would like to create a simple fluid web layout with Twitter Bootstrap. It should look like this on the computer:

[image: computer layout]

and like this on mobile device (that breaking up images into two locations is optional, but preferable):

[image: mobile layout]

When I created it, it works perfectly on Firefox's Fluid layout view, but looks different on mobile with Android.

How it looks on Android:

[image]

Those two lists are staying on the same line for some reason.

The code:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span2">
    <img><br>
    <img>
  </div>

  <div class="span10">
    <p>text</p>

    <ul class="span5">
      <li>bullet</li>
      <li>bullet</li>
      <li>bullet</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="span5">
      <li>bullet</li>
      <li>bullet</li>
      <li>bullet</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="span12">
    <p>other text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or should I use class media? Media object for images and media-body for the rest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have started a nested row in the block of code

```
<div class="span10">
<p>text</p>
<ul class="span5"> 
....
</ul>
<ul class="span5"> 
....
</ul>
```

What you want for the Bootstrap grid to work correctly is

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row-fluid">

  <div class="span2">
   <img><br>
   <img>
  </div> <!-- end span 2 -->

<div class="span10">
 <p>text</p>

 <div class="row-fluid"> <!-- start nested row -->

  <ul class="span6">
   <li>bullet</li>
   <li>bullet</li>
   <li>bullet</li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="span6">
   <li>bullet</li>
   <li>bullet</li>
   <li>bullet</li>
   </ul>

  </div> <!-- end nested row -->

  </div><!-- end span10 -->

  <div class="span12">
  <p>other text</p>
  </div><!-- end span12 -->

 </div><!-- end row-fluid -->

 </div><!-- end container -->
```

For nested fluid rows, you want the spans of nested columns to add up to 12, not 10 in your case. See fluid nesting @ http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem for full details.

Good luck!